# weird behaviour of c++ maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, g++

Here's the code

```
next = friendchain.begin()->first;
while(true) {
    start = next;
    next = friendchain[next];

    if(next!=0) {
        friendchain.erase(start);
        groupcount++;
        size = friendchain.size();
        printf("size=%i\n", size);
        //size = 0
    }

    if (next==0) {
        size = friendchain.size();
        printf("size=%i\n", size);
        //size = 1!!!

        if (friendchain.empty())
        {
            break;
            //should go out of the loop here
        } else {
            next = friendchain.begin()->first;
            // next has value of 3   
        }
    }
}
```

the contents of my friendchain map are :
1 -> 2 and
2 -> 3
I dont understand why the else part is getting executed.
let me know if you need more code.
regards

Comment: your question is terrible. I didn't downvote, and your code is also bad, use iterators to traverse your map, then you wouldn't need to check if it's emtpy

Comment: please show at least the types of friendchain next and start

Comment: I am using maps for the first time and am still learning the lang  referring c++ docs and didnt get any solution there . @PorkyBrain start and next is long.

Answer (score 1):

I removed a few if-statements that were not needed and you were not handling the erase correctly.

```
auto itr = friendchain.begin();
while (itr != friendchain.end()) {
    if (itr->first != 0) {
        friendchain.erase(itr++);
        groupcount++;
    } else {
        ++itr;
    }

    std::size_t size = friendchain.size();
    printf("size=%i\n", size);
}
```